# How to get the logfilepath in the log analytics workspace in Azure monitoring?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have an azure system where I am redirecting multiple log files in the log analytics workspace as below (pasting part of my json file below):

```
 "dataSources": {
        "value": {
            "logFiles": [
                {
                    "name": "rbac_customlogs_CL",
                    "streams": [
                        "Custom-rbac_customlogs_CL"
                    ],
                    "filePatterns": [
                        "/urs/lib/Logs/*.txt"
                    ],
                    "format": "text",
                    "settings": {
                        "text": {
                            "recordStartTimestampFormat": "ISO 8601"
                        }
                    }
```

The path value mentioned in filepatterns property above has a lot of file paths :-

```
/urs/lib/Logs/delimiter.txt
/urs/lib/Logs/closure.txt
/urs/lib/Logs/department.txt
```

So while I have created a log analytics custom table, all the logs from these sources are sending their logs in this table called rbac_customlogs_CL

I want to write a KQL query or may be find a way by which I can print the log file name also as one of the column in the kql query result set, something like :-

```
rbac_customlogs_CL
 | where filepath contains "/urs/lib/Logs/department.txt"
```

and it should return the logs from this file path only.